# How to redefine label such that it recognizes its environment

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

How to redefine `label` command such that if it is inside a environment (e.g. theorem) then `\label{thm:2}` becomes `\label[Theorem]{thm:2}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=green]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}

\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}


\begin{document}
\section{Bla Bla}

\begin{lemma}\label{noname}% This becomes \label[Lemma]{noname} automaticaly  
  A lemma that has no name.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[My Lemma]\label{lem:a}% This becomes \label[Lemma]{lem:a}  automaticaly
  This is some statement.
\end{lemma}

\begin{thm}[My Theorem]\label{thm:b}% This becomes \label[Theorem]{thm:b} automaticaly
  This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have commented out cleveref but by default `\label` does not have an optional argument so it is not clear what you want `\label[Theorem]{thm:b}` to do in the absence of `cleveref` ?

Comment: Is it meaningless? Ok. its my fault. I'll fix it.

Comment: it is not an error but it would make the label be `[` and would typeset `Theorem]thm:b`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's real typesetting issues are (a) not really related to the code he/she posted and (b) depend on pieces of information that the OP apparently is not willing to share.

Comment: @Mico- That's not important that what is my problem really, my question is very simple: how to convert `\label{thm:2}` to `\label[Theorem]{thm:2}` automatically?

Comment: You've provided no information as to how the `Theorem` counter might be defined. There's nothing in your posting about a counter named `Theorem`. Might it be related to `thm`? If so, how? There's no reason to believe that an answer which changes `\label{thm:2}` to `\label[Theorem]{thm:2}`, automatically or by hand, actually solves anything.

Comment: Usually the macro `\@currenvir` expands to the name of the current environment. Perhaps you can do something like  `\makeatletter\newcommand\CurrEnvLabel[1]{\label[\@currenvir]{#1}}\makeatother` and use `\CurrEnvLabel` instead of `\label` within your `lemma`- and `thm`-environments.

Comment: @UlrichDiez- thanks for your attention.